# Apigee 4G Production configurations

Tags: performance, config, apigee

Does anyone have any guidance based on experience of what system and applications setting in PROD will need to be tweaked.

Aside from the text below (which is in the OPDK docs), what needs to be upped on the various systems?

Depending on your traffic and processing requirements you may need to increase the heap and/or permgen sizes for one or more Apigee components. To change the heap and permgen settings, locate the “apigee-env.sh” script in the /opt/apigee4/bin directory on the machine on which the components you want to modify are running, and change the values of “min_mem”, “max_mem” and “max_permgen” as appropriate. Please note that these values affect all Apigee processes running on this machine, so care should be taken that any changes you make do not adversely affect the operation of the system as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the JVM parameters another one I come across most frequently is the HTTP configuration. A number of system level defaults for various HTTP properties can be tuned using the properties file at ${APIGEE_HOME}/mp/conf/http.properties

Comment: on my system it is in /<APIGEE_HOME>/conf/apigee/message-processor and in /<APIGEE_HOME>/conf/apigee/router

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the //conf/apigee/message-processor/http.properties...

I see these two entries:

```
# if commented there will be no limit
HTTPTransport.max.client.count=10000
```

and

```
# if the active client count of HTTPServer reaches the specified value,
# then any new clients requesting for keepalive connection will be rejected
# by sending 'connection: close' in Response
# defaults to 96
# -1 means there is no limit
#HTTPServer.max.keepalive.clients=96
```

Is the HTTPTransport.max.client.count the number of connections to target services this MP will maintain or the number of inbound connections?

Is HTTPServer.max.keepalive.clients the number of persistent connections to the MP or from the MP to target services?  If this is from  the MP to target endpoints, isn't that very low at 96?

Comment: See similar query here https://community.apigee.com/questions/12932/what-do-the-message-processorrouter-properties-htt.html